# Checking a network connection in a loop never succeeds even if the connection is available

Tags: ruby, networking

I want to check for a connection to a specific server with Ruby. So I just wrap the HTTP request into a begin/rescue construct and try again in a few seconds if the connection is not available.

Problem:  If I start the program with no connection available (link down) it will never succeed in finding a connection even if at some time the connection is available (e.g. via ping, browser request).

Code:

```
require 'net/http'

loop do 

    begin
        uri = URI.parse 'http://www.example.com'
        resp = Net::HTTP.get uri
    rescue SocketError => se
        puts se
        sleep 3
        next
    rescue Exception => e
        puts e
        break   
    end

    puts 'It works!'
    break

end
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Take network link down
2. Start program
3. -> **getaddrinfo: Name or service not known**
4. -> ...
5. Turn network link on again
6. Still no connection, same error

Why is that?

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Works on mine, ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32] (win8-x64)

Comment: Thanks for your info. So this may be a bug in Linux - I will wait if someone has a solution to this, otherwise file a bug report, I think.

Comment: Works as well : ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

Comment: I created a bug report: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8067

Comment: AS an aside you should be using retry (http://jackchu.com/blog/2012/02/09/retrying-a-block-of-ruby-code-if-it-fails/) for this. It leads to much nicer code :).